# Find the values of the largest key of an association

Tags: associations

I have an association:

```
1->{10,50,100}, 2->{2,4,6,9,60,90}, 3->{3,7,12,1425}, 4->{8,13,17,22,24,26,29}, 5->{18,23,27,32,97}, 6->{28,33,37,48,98}, 7->{38,78}, 8->{88}
```

I want to get the value of the largest key i.e. 8, from the above association i.e. 88. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: The function `KeySort` might also be notable in case you want to perform several of such iindexing by ordering of the keys; then you can order once `a = KeySort[a]` and access smallest and largest key by `a[[1]]` and `a[[-1]]` (and so on...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
assoc = Association[1 -> {1, 5, 10, 50, 100}, 
  2 -> {2, 4, 6, 9, 11, 15, 20, 40, 51, 55, 60, 90}, 
  3 -> {3, 7, 12, 14, 16, 19, 21, 25, 30, 41, 45, 52, 54, 56, 59, 61, 
    65, 70, 91, 95}, 
  4 -> {8, 13, 17, 22, 24, 26, 29, 31, 35, 42, 44, 46, 49, 53, 57, 62,
     64, 66, 69, 71, 75, 80, 92, 94, 96, 99}, 
  5 -> {18, 23, 27, 32, 34, 36, 39, 43, 47, 58, 63, 67, 72, 74, 76, 
    79, 81, 85, 93, 97}, 
  6 -> {28, 33, 37, 48, 68, 73, 77, 82, 84, 86, 89, 98}, 
  7 -> {38, 78, 83, 87}, 8 -> {88}];


assoc[Max @ Keys @ assoc]
```

> ```
> {88}
> ```

Also

```
MaximalBy[First] @ assoc (* thanks: @swish *)
```

> ```
> <|8 -> {88}|>
> ```

Comment: `MaximalBy` works on associations, no need for `Normal`.

Comment: thank you @swish. Updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function[x, x@*Max@AssociationMap[Reverse][x]]@assoc
```

although I would use the method proposed by @kglr i.e.

```
assoc[Max @ Keys @ assoc]
```